# I need help populating an attached excel template in access db via a query of data and then export to excel file onto users system

Tags: excel, vba, templates, ms-access, attachment

I had seen sample code from "Gord" below - I would like to maintain excel templates in my access front end and have them updated as needed by the user by running a select query and populating the excel template and then save the template to the users directory of choice. In the code below I cannot figure out the "FileData" and "FileName".

Here is a sample of typical output from my query:

```
CY  Month   Avg Count
2019    1   12.00   43
2019    2   11.00   42
2019    3   10.00   67
2019    4   13.00   43
2019    5   11.00   33
2019    6   9.80    23
```

This data goes into the excel template which then performs some tasks and makes graphs. The months can vary from 1 month to 12 months.

I have been working on this for a while - the example by Gord is the closest I have found. I can set up an external template on the LAN and such but that seems slow.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public Sub SaveReportTemplateToFile()
    Dim cdb As DAO.Database, rowRst As DAO.Recordset, attachRst As DAO.Recordset2, attachField As DAO.Field2
    Set cdb = CurrentDb
    Set rowRst = cdb.OpenRecordset("SELECT TemplateFile FROM ReportTemplates WHERE ID=1")
    Set attachRst = rowRst.Fields("TemplateFile").Value
    Set attachField = attachRst.Fields("FileData")
    attachField.SaveToFile "C:\Users\Gord\Desktop\" & attachRst.Fields("FileName").Value
    Set attachField = Nothing
    attachRst.Close
    Set attachRst = Nothing
    rowRst.Close
    Set rowRst = Nothing
    Set cdb = Nothing
End Sub
```

I am stuck with how to populate the data into the excel template, which is an attachment in the database, and the FileName. Also, in this example, is the data only stored in the exported file?

Comment: Probably have to extract Excel file to external folder location, edit, then save wherever. You seem to already have the extract part down. So exactly what is issue? Why save objects within table?

Comment: As for code to export data to Excel workbook, review http://www.accessmvp.com/KDSnell/EXCEL_Export.htm

Comment: in the example code I am getting hung up on the "FileData" and "FileName" - I really like the idea of holding the templates in Access for a variety of reasons and if I could figure out how to populate the template and then save then I would be thrilled beyond belief.

Comment: Why are you hung up on FileData and FileName? Those are correct references for an attachment type field. Do this as learning exercise: open query builder and bring in the table with that attachment field - you should see the attachment field has 3 parts.

Comment: Thanks June7 - I haven't used attachments so this is a new concept for me. Your suggestion was very helpful. My goal is to have the user select certain parameters (like year, month range, product) and then click a button where the query results are exported to the excel template, save the new Excel file to a location of the users choice, and then open Excel where the template performs certain calculations and displays a chart. If there is a better way of doing this I am open for ideas. Thank you so much for the ideas.

Comment: I am struggling with how to move the data from my query to the excel template. If I have an excel template saved in access as an attachment do I save the data as a multivalue field in the Attachments table? Thanks!

Comment: Why would you save data to a multi-value field? Sounds like you have not done any research to learn about multi-value/attachment fields to understand what they are and how they really work. Did you review the Ken Snell link referenced in second comment? If you have new code with issue, edit question or start a new one.